# How does Maven identify plugins without group ID on the command line?

Tags: maven

With Maven, I can run a command like this from the command line and it works:

```
mvn compiler:compile
```

How does Maven know which plugin I want to use, even though I did not provide a group ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maven plugins typically follow one of two naming conventions:

- `${name}-maven-plugin`
- `maven-${name}-plugin` (reserved for Apache Maven project plugins)

Plugins that follow one of the conventions, such as the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) or the [`wildfly-maven-plugin`](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/index.html), can be used via their shortened version on the command line; `compiler` or `wildfly`. This makes it so you don't need to provide the fully qualified `groupId:artifactId:version:command` form.

You could absolutely do something like:

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile` to use its fully qualified name, but obviously the shortened form is much easier to work with.

There are a handful of other ways to provide shortened forms. The [plugin development guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) gives some good detail on this, specifically paragraph ["shortening the command line"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#shortening-the-command-line).

---

**Update by *kriegaex*:** Maven also by default seems to only search group IDs `org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo`, so if you run something like

```
mvn buildplan:list-phase
```

the result will be

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'buildplan' in the current project and
        in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
        available from the repositories
```

If you want more comfort on the command line, i.e. not specify the group ID `fr.jcgay.maven.plugins` in this case, add this to `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```xml
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>fr.jcgay.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Comment: I added a direct link to "shortening the command line" to your helpful answer. I have been using Maven for years, but never really knew about it and was just wondering lately while using something like mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3 how it actually works, because I did not specify Versions Maven in my POM. I also added info about how to add more default plugin groups. Sorry to mess with your answer, but I find it valuable and did not want to add another one, because you deserve the upvotes IMO.